# Jdeveloper 12c web service does not return a result xml

Tags: xml, xsd, jdeveloper, bpel

**I have created a webservice that does not return a result xml, despite assigning a filled, well formed and correct xml to the output variable.**

Unfortunately, I am a newby with JDeveloper, webservices and the like. It is therefore most likely a rather simple fix.

I confirmed that the "insert missing to Data" is checked, the flow trace, when set to Development level, confirms that all xml files are filled by the assign activities and that the output variable truly is the designated output.

The result xml is 154 KB large (maybe that is too large?).

I appreciate help in all forms and would like to thank you in advance.

**Additional Information:**

As we do not have foreign keys in our database (Yes, I know, and no, I cannot fix that as I am only the apprentice and everybody else is fine with it), I could not just create one database adapter, but had to create 3 and collect the data in one big xml via a BPEL process. Furthermore, I am the first to work with JDeveloper and thus none of my colleagues can assist me.

The result xml looks like this. Not all elements are filled, yet every element is nillable (only on the lowest level).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Contract>
     <Table1>
       <Table1Data />
       <Table1Data />
       <Table1Data />
       <Table1Data />
     </Table1>
     <Table2>
       <Table2Data />
       <Table2Data />
       <Table2Data />
       <Table2Data />
     </Table2>
     <Table3Collection>
       <Table3>
         <Table3 Data />
         <Table3 Data />
         <Table3 Data />
       </Table3>
       <Table3>
         <Table3 Data />
         <Table3 Data />
         <Table3 Data />
       </Table3>
       <Table3>
         <Table3 Data />
         <Table3 Data />
         <Table3 Data />
       </Table3>
     </Table3Collection>
   </Contract>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as said, it was an easy fix. I used an asynchronous call to the web service collecting the data. This does result in the empty testing result.

After I added a synchronous web service with a BPEL process calling and recieving from the first web serice, I did get the desired output.